# Using Netbeans 8.0.0 and Glassfish 4.1 getting error 2 servlets have same URL pattern

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans, glassfish

I am new to Java EE and wanted to go through the *Affablebean* tutorial. First I wanted to be sure that it worked so I downloaded the "answer" from the Netbeans site.

I setup everything as instructed and it builds, but when I try to run it I get:

> SEVERE:   Servlet [RegistrationPortImpl] and Servlet
>   [RegistrationRequesterPortImpl] have the same url pattern:
>   [/RegistrationService_V11] SEVERE:   Exception while deploying the app
>   [AffableBean] SEVERE:   Exception during lifecycle processing

I've researched and found numerous mentions of this but no answer or even a place to start. These Servlets are part of Glassfish, and come that way in the jar. I'm hoping that this is just a newbie issue and others have seen it and can at least tell me where to start.

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of fruitless trial-and-error, I came across a post about this on a different forum. Although it wasn't exactly the same it was close enough. The problem is that Glassfish and the basic Java collide during deployment for those Servlets. However, the jar I needed is required to compile. so I went into Netbeans, selected the Projects tab went to Libraries right-clicked and selected Properties. It put me to a screen where I saw the Compile libraries. I selected the "Java EE from Glassfish" library and hit edit. That took me to a list of jars. I selected the webservices-osgi.jar and deleted it from the list. Then I went back up to the Compile library list and hit Add JAR. I browsed over the the glassfish-4.1\glassfish\modules\ dir and selected webservices-osgi.jar BUT I did NOT check the checkbox for Package. Then I did a clean/build and run.

Comment: In my case i add 2 of them endorsed/webservices-osgi.jar and modules/webservices-osgi.jar . I deleted both, add the JAR has told by davef and remove de Java-EE package checkbox and it worked ;).
My netbeans is 8.0.2 btw glassfish 4.1

Comment: In my case I had changed package "payara-embedded-all" from test scope to normal scope.  It worked initially, while my server was still up, so I forgot about it.  But then it stopped working when I tried to restart the server.

Comment: If you are using maven,  org.glassfish.metro.webservices-rt-x.x.jar should be set as scope "provided"